# Datatable not showing search & sort

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to make a very simple page to preview my records in database.

I want to use datatable so I can sort & search. Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <script data-rocketsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/dt-1.10.11/datatables.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketsrc="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/dt-1.10.11/datatables.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    </table>
    <script type="text/rocketscript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

But for some reason the datatable is not working, there is no search / sort function there. What am I missing?

Comment: Your table is empty with no columns or data, that's why there is no search or sort available.

Comment: I removed the tr & td so the code is shorter. But there is content in the actual code though

Answer (score -1):

Use either of the code blocks below to load jQuery DataTables.

For example, use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/dt-1.10.11/datatables.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/dt-1.10.11/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or use [`data-cfasync="false"`](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436-How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-my-script-s-in-Automatic-Mode-) attribute:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/dt-1.10.11/datatables.min.css"/>
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketsrc="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/dt-1.10.11/datatables.min.js"></script>
```